# How can I line up images using ActiveRecord

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, activerecord, rubygems

I am using Rails to achieve the following effect for a beauty item sales site
[image]

Assuming I have the information stored on the DB how can I generate or display the items as shown in the picture while giving the user the option to click "Next" and continue viewing the other items. Is there a gem for this ?

Also, I would like to achieve the same effect of clicking "Add to Basket" and then have it change to a quantity text field with - + on the sides.

Any libraries/gems for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Displaying an 8 column grid of products is a bit specific for a gem. Your question doesn't really have anything to do with ActiveRecord, it's a view question.

If you need a starting point on the front end, I suggest checking out twitter bootstrap. It has a grid system that is very flexible.

As to the increment decrement buttons you just need to use jquery to update the text field depending on which one is clicked.